# Google TreeMap fill value set to _ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1

Tags: javascript, html, svg, google-visualization, treemap

I am using a google tree map to render some data. I have a problem with showScale component. When the tree map renders, the showScale component is completely black when it should show a e gradient between minColor and maxColor.

The `fill` attribute of the svg component is set as follows :

```
fill="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1)"
```

Can you explain what _ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1  is ?

Comment: I had this problem due to parenthesis in the path-name to the html file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283410/google-visualisation-not-working-with-local-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be either a gradient fill or a pattern fill.

Somewhere else in the file - probably in a `<defs>` section - will be one of the following elements with an `id` attribute that matches that string:

```
<linearGradient>
<radialGradient>
<pattern>
```

Comment: I have this problem but still can't figure out where this is, how to fix it, or how I broke it...

Comment: Made some progress: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283410/google-visualisation-not-working-with-local-file .  Loading the file from local FS prevents `#` anchors from working, which is how the def is connected to the fill.  Only solution so far is to run from web server (IIS)